# Best way to deal with potentially very large form creating/posting using jquery $.download

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, internet-explorer, download

I have a process as follows:

1. User does a complex search that is done ajaxly that returns a bunch of ids (could be 1, could be 10000)
2. Once they have there users, they can select a few things and then they download a file (which is a report based on the ids, and the things they select)

To accomplish this, I use a highly modified version of [$.download](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/)

seen here:

```
jQuery.download = function (url, data, method, loadingHolderDivId) {
if (url && typeof data == 'object') {
    //for this version, data needs to be a json object.  
    //loop through the data object..
    $('#' + loadingHolderDivId).html($('#LoadingScreen').html());
    
    var theForm = $('<form></form>').attr('action', url).attr('method', method).attr('id', 'jqueryDownloadForm').attr('target', 'iframeX');

    $.each(data, function (propertyName, propertyVal) {
        if (propertyVal != null) {
            if (typeof propertyVal == 'object') {

                //HANDLE ARRAYS!
                for (var i = 0, len = propertyVal.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    theForm.append($("<input />").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('id', propertyName + i.toString).attr('name', propertyName).val(propertyVal[i]));
                }
            }
            else {
                theForm.append($("<input />").attr('type', 'hidden').attr('id', propertyName).attr('name', propertyName).val(propertyVal));
            }
        }
    });


    var iframeX;
    var downloadInterval;

    // remove old iframe if has
    $("#iframeX").remove();
    // create new iframe
    iframeX = $('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="iframeX" id="iframeX"></iframe>').appendTo('body').hide();

    if ($.browser.msie) {
        downloadInterval = setInterval(function () {
            // if loading then readyState is “loading” else readyState is “interactive”
            if (iframeX && iframeX[0].readyState !== "loading") {
                $('#' + loadingHolderDivId).empty();
                clearInterval(downloadInterval);
            }
        }, 23);
    }
    else {
        iframeX.load(function () {
            $('#' + loadingHolderDivId).empty();
        });
    }


    theForm.appendTo('body').trigger('submit').remove();
    return false;
}
else {
    //they didn't fill in the params.  do nothing
}


};
```

Basically what is does is parses what's in data, and builds a form out of it.  this works great, when there isn't a lot of ids.   but when there is 8000, it takes 5 or 10 seconds in IE, no surprise really, it's well know IE sucks at dom manipulation.

The other issue is, in IE.  the `$('#' + loadingHolderDivId).html($('#LoadingScreen').html());`  won't actually happen until after it's done building the form.  I am guessing this is because it takes a second to do that, and before it can finish it's already to busy building the form.

The reason I am building out the form this way is so that the default model binder will be happy and bind my form right into a lovely model. The list of ids is being bound to an ilist (of integer)

Here is a sample of what the controller action looks like:

```
Function ExportUsers(ByVal model As ExportUsersPostModel) As ActionResult
```

and here's an example of what the model looks like:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class ExportUsersPostModel
    Public Property FilterUserIds As IList(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    Public Property FilterColumnIds As IList(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    public property ShowThis as boolean
    public property OtherStuff as string = string.empty
    Public Property FormatId As Integer
End Class
```

so the actual question is two fold:

1. How do I make my "loading" message show up before it begins the horribly slow form building of death?
2. How can I speed up the form building, or build the form in a way that won't be slow, but that will still keep the model binder happy?

Comment: why are you creating a form element instead of using plain `$.post()` ? DOM manipulation is killing your performance. (you can keep the model binder happy using `$.post()` )

Comment: you can't use ajax to get a file!

Comment: You could use `$.post`, store the data in temp on the server, return a key, then navigate to a download page with the key to get the file.

Comment: As far as just speeding up your existing code, `$("<input />")` is much slower than `document.createElement("input")`. JQuery isn't always the solution.

Comment: re: using $.post,  not really an option.  but a neat idea. 
re: using document.createElement.  good call, didn't think of that.

Comment: +1 for a good question and for telling it like it is for IE.  My question to you is, if you save all that information in a single variable and do nothing else with it, is it faster?  In other words, is it the dom manipulation which causes it to be sluggish?  If so, perhaps we can find an alternative.

Comment: Neil: yea, sticking them all in one input speeds it up significantly... BUT... that does cause it's own problems,  it maxes out the allowed size for a single form input and doesn't send anything.   unless i change the encoding type, which i suppose isn't so bad.  The model binder just doesn't know what to do with it then.

Comment: Have you looked at creating a custom Model Binder to cope with a single, serialized input field?

Comment: i've got an attribute that handles json data and converts it to a model.  but, b/c this has files, i can't use that, it requires the type to be json/whatever. 

if i could make a model binder or attribute or something that can just translate the one comma separated string to the list of integer, and use the regular model binder for the rest... but i have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to pass the model across as JSON, you can create a custom ModelBinder to handle mapping the JSON to your data structure. I did that recently for an object type that could not be mapped automatically. [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) provides a class called JObject which takes a JSON string and maps it to a dynamic C# object. You can then map the dynamic object to your strongly typed object.

To create a custom ModelBinder, simply create a class that inherits from IModelBinder and implement the BindModel method. Here is a copy of my implementation. Yours will obviously vary slightly:

```
internal class FilterBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        if ((controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Count > 1 || (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Count == 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys[0]))) || (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Count > 1 || (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Count == 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys[0]))))
        {
            ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            string value = val == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.AttemptedValue) ? string.Empty : val.AttemptedValue;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;
            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(value);
            return new FilterSet(obj);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

I have a bunch of checks to make sure what I'm getting is valid, which you may or may not need. Then, after getting the JObject, I pass it along to my constructor which does the mapping.

Comment: ahhh interesting, so your saying, put all the data into one form field as a json object, and then submit it and use this custom model binder to turn that into my model... of course!

Comment: i'm working on implimenting this... my project is in vb.net though.  and i can't figure out: FilterSet(obj);'   what's filterset?

Comment: alright, so i didn't end up using this but, it lead me to my final solution, which was sending the lists of integers as one string field, and having a read only property on the model that turns them into the lists(of integer)   thanks for the idea!

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity on my code. The FilterSet object is my custom object that I created. It's basically the statically typed version of the JSON object passed back.

I'm glad that I could help you find a solution to your problem!

Comment: ooooh, ok, so that's just casting the obj to your type. that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe it's just me, but iFrame + trying to ajax a file download + 10+ seconds per query (possibly) = cloog.  Maybe it's my years as a UI engineer focusing on what the client sees, but I've got a real problem making somebody wait that long on one of my applications.  There has to be a better way, and I think it can be improved on the UI end of things.

In a nutshell, you need to do a big search, drill down to specifics, then dump data.  So, user-pattern-wise, I'd start by looking at options to achieve each task.

The search is easy....send a pattern to the server, get a result back.  Nothing magic here, though Ajax would probably be a nice touch.

Now, the "drill down" of data.  Since you're potentially dealing with a LOT of data here, you need a way to allow the user to quickly and easily get through the mountain of "stuff" in an organized and efficient manner.  To me, this is screaming for a grid.  My preference is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net).  What this buys you is efficiency, organization, paging, and most of all the ability for the user to easily interact with the data to pick out "stuff."  Your ajax query from step 1 would populate DataTables via [ajax "pipelining"](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)  That is, it would grab what the user wants to see-- say 25 results -- and grab ahead of and possibly behind a bit to speed up the interface.  All the data would be available, it just would be grabbed a section at a time, which speeds up the query.  The user could sort, filter, order, and limit the data on the interface, making it easier for them to [highlight to select data](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html).

Now, onto step 3, a downloadable report.  To make it REALLY easy, Datatables has a plugin called ["TableTools"](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) that will automatically spit out Excel, PDF, Text, and Printable versions of the data you're offering the user.  It's a few lines of code and a couple of images.....takes about 10 minutes to configure.  Voila, done.  Yeah, it's --that-- simple.

As for being able to handle that many records, yeah it does.  I've got an app with 2.5 million records being handled in this manner via a standard MySQL database (not clustered)  Because you're only grabbing a "slice" of data at a time, it's never having to do any exotic, gigantic queries aside from a record count.  The user can page through results with just a tiny, occasional delay.  It really is a thing of beauty.

Comment: the searching for the users is fast! that's not the issue, they get the users they want to report on ajaxly, it's done in < 1 second.  but we have to send that list of users back to the server, with the form to generate the report,  the reports are all ms reporting service reports, they are complex, and couldn't be generated using any handy dandy tools.  you make some very good points, but in this case, it won't solve the problem.

Comment: @Patricia, there's a million different ways to skin this cat.  My point is to step back as a developer and think UI for a minute.  Google Analytics handles a similar problem by "scheduling" a report that the user can then fetch.  It's a great solution because it removes the "waiting" for something to happen and gives the expectation that "we're working, come back in a bit" which is usually only a few seconds to a minute.  Try it once, it's really an appealing pattern and can make up on the user end for a process that takes more than a second or two to do.  You can even alert when it's ready.